# SQL Server query for SUM based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below:

```
fld_bank_cash_particular_id  fld_cr_dr  fld_account_id  fld_amount
1                            Dr         26              1000
2                            Dr         26              2000
3                            Dr         26              3000
4                            Cr         26              4000
5                            Dr         26              5000
6                            Cr         26              6000
7                            Dr         26              7000
8                            Dr         26              8000
9                            Dr         26              9000
10                           Cr         26              10000
11                           Dr         27              1000
12                           Dr         27              2000
13                           Dr         27              3000
14                           Cr         27              4000
15                           Dr         27              5000
16                           Cr         27              6000
17                           Dr         27              7000
18                           Dr         27              8000
19                           Dr         27              9000
20                           Cr         27              1000
```

I want SUM() of all amount with column value 'Dr' as Payments and SUM() of all amount with column value 'Cr' as Receipts[Result should display AccountId wise Payments and Receipts]. Same Output like below:

```
AccountId   Payments    Receipts
26          35000       20000
27          35000       20000
```

Currently i'm getting below result:

```
AccountId   Payments    Receipts
26          0           20000
26          35000       0
27          0           20000
27          35000       0
```

Comment: You describe one table.  Then you have a complicated query that seems to have nothing to do with the table.  What is your real question?

Comment: I want output like i mentioned above.

Comment: Remove the group by on tbcep.fld_cr_dr and only group on the tam.fld_account_id

Comment: Query does not match.  You provide only one table.   Only include enough information to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work!
It is easy and clear!

```
  SELECT 
      DR.AccountId
     ,Payments
     ,Receipts
    FROM
    (
     (SELECT 
         fld_account_id AccountId
         ,SUM(fld_amount) Payments
        FROM table_name
        WHERE fld_cr_dr = 'Dr'
        GROUP BY fld_account_id) DR
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT 
         fld_account_id AccountId
         ,SUM(fld_amount) Receipts
        FROM table_name
        WHERE fld_cr_dr = 'Cr'
        GROUP BY fld_account_id) CR ON DR.AccountId = CR.AccountId
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "TestTable" with your table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountID, COALESCE(SumPay, 0) AS Payments, COALESCE(SumRec, 0) AS Receipts
FROM (SELECT fld_account_id AS AccountID
    , (SELECT SUM([fld_amount]) FROM TestTable WHERE fld_cr_dr = 'Dr' AND fld_account_id = t.fld_account_id) AS SumPay
    , (SELECT SUM([fld_amount]) FROM TestTable WHERE fld_cr_dr = 'Cr' AND fld_account_id = t.fld_account_id) AS SumRec
FROM TestTable t) AS tmp
```

...may not be the most efficient, as it runs duplicate queries, but unless you're running it a hundred times a minute and/or your table is millions of records long, it should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT tam.fld_account_id AS [Account Id], 
MAX(CASE WHEN tbcep.fld_cr_dr = 'Dr' THEN SUM(ISNULL(fld_amount,0)) ELSE 0 
END) AS Payments,
MAX(CASE WHEN tbcep.fld_cr_dr = 'Cr' THEN SUM(ISNULL(fld_amount,0)) ELSE 0 
END) AS Receipts
FROM tbl_bank_cash_entry_particulars tbcep
INNER JOIN tbl_bank_cash_entry tbce 
ON tbce.fld_bank_cash_entry_id = tbcep.fld_bank_cash_entry_id 
AND tbce.fld_fy_id=1 AND tbce.fld_is_active=1 AND tbce.fld_is_delete=0
LEFT JOIN tbl_account_master tam 
ON tam.fld_account_id = tbcep.fld_account_id 
AND tam.fld_is_active=1 AND tam.fld_is_delete=0
WHERE tam.fld_account_group_id=36 
AND tbcep.fld_is_active=1 AND tbcep.fld_is_delete=0
            GROUP BY tam.fld_account_id
```

USE MAX to select only the max value. so this approach will give you output in a single row

Comment: This Provides below error `Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`